# error: can't find main(String[]) method in class:

Tags: java, java-shebang

In a **Java shebang script** I get this crazy `error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: gomad.MyKotlin` and the 1st question I ask to myself is: "WHY on Earth does it look for the `main()` method in that class?" (UPD Well, this does reproduce when java compiles-and-runs a single-file program.)

```
#!/usr/bin/java --source 11

package gomad;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static gomad.MyKotlin.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        int[] x = MyArrays.sorted(3, 14, 15, 92, 6, 53, 58, 97, 93, 2, 38, 4, 62, 6, 43);
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(x).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}

class MyKotlin { // the idea of also() comes from Kotlin
    static <T> T also(T obj, Consumer<T> action) {
        action.accept(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}

class MyArrays {
    static int[] sorted(int ... xs) {
        return also(xs, Arrays::sort);
    }
}
```

In the case of this script, the message is `error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: gomad.MyKotlin`.

When this program is run from IntelliJ Idea with she-bang commented out, everything works.

It is important to note that when this program is run as `java Main.java`, the same senseless `error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: gomad.MyKotlin` appears.
But If you try to run it as `javac gomad/Main.java && java gomad.Main`, you get the expected result, no error.

```
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin/java Main.java
error: can't find main(String[]) method in class: gomad.MyKotlin
$ /usr/lib/jvm/java-21-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -version
openjdk version "21.0.2" 2024-01-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 21.0.2+13-Ubuntu-122.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.2+13-Ubuntu-122.04.1, mixed mode, sharing)
```

And this has nothing to do with Kotlin except that `also()` is borrowed from Kotlin.

*Folks, I know that this looks like a duplicate, but it isn't. The other discussions say that the class with `main()` must be declared first (which is true), and that one should use `javac` then `java`, which is not exactly how she-bang scripts work. This is Q&A-style and I post my solution along with this question. If you know why it happens and how it may be avoided without having to desist from using some language constructs, please contribute.*

Comment: This looks like a bug. You should report it if you haven't.

Comment: I think this question would be better if you removed the misleading clues from it. Is this about the shebang? No, you mention in the answer that this can be reproduced with just a single-source-file java program without the shebang. Is this about Kotlin? No, it's just about Java, so rename your second class.

Comment: @Sören If I remove the reference to Kotlin, I will be asked why I use such strange functionality and such a strange name. If I remove the mention of a shebang, I will be told to use `javac && java` instead.

Comment: Bug report created at https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8328339

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to fix it, but I know a workaround.
The workaround is: ***remove any static imports for local classes.***
Java seems to search for `main()` in the class mentioned in the first static import.
So in this case if we ***remove:***

```
import static gomad.MyKotlin.*;
```

and replace

```
    return also(xs, Arrays::sort);
```

with

```
    return MyKotlin.also(xs, Arrays::sort);
```

and then everything works (but becomes cumbersome).

Comment: Java version ? in java 21 it should run correctly...
I guess because its Kotlin you will need to compile first the file to .class files...

Comment: @firephil same problem with Java 21.0.2, Jan 16 2024. And Kotlin is just a name, a hint where `also()` has been borrowed from.

Answer (score 0):

There are more workarounds.

The 2nd workaround is rather a bad news. If you add the `main()` method to the class where Java says it expects to see it, it will work. At least, until the moment that your code changes so that Java will expect to find `main()` somewhere else.

This abomination works:

```
#!/usr/bin/java --source 11

package gomad;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static gomad.MyArrays.sorted;
import static gomad.MyKotlin.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
        int[] x = sorted(3, 14, 15, 92, 6, 53, 58, 97, 93, 2, 38, 4, 62, 6, 43);
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(x).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}

class MyKotlin {
    static <T> T also(T obj, Consumer<T> action) {
        action.accept(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}

class MyArrays {
    static int[] sorted(int ... xs) {
        return also(xs, Arrays::sort);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { // FACEPALM
        Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

And the 3rd workaround is to create a class with a reference to statically imported `main()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/java --source 11

package gomad;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static gomad.Main.main;
import static gomad.MyArrays.sorted;
import static gomad.MyKotlin.*;

class Irrelevant {
    void irrelevant() {
        main(); // not used, but compiled first
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println("Hello world of " + Arrays.asList(args));
        int[] x = sorted(3, 14, 15, 92, 6, 53, 58, 97, 93, 2, 38, 4, 62, 6, 43);
        System.out.println(Arrays.stream(x).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}

class MyKotlin {
    static <T> T also(T obj, Consumer<T> action) {
        action.accept(obj);
        return obj;
    }
}

class MyArrays {
    static int[] sorted(int ... xs) {
        return also(xs, Arrays::sort);
    }
}
```